# Is it must to pass SparkConf parameter from ADF pipeline to reflect in Spark job

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory

We are using custom activity in MS Azure ADF and configuring Spark job.
We have set all `SparkConf` parameters in code like below:

```
.set("spark.app.name","SparkAppForStudent")
.set("spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.allowBatching", "true")
.set("spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.batchingTimeout", "60000")
.set("spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable", "true")
```

These parameters are not reflecting in Spark job.
Do we need to pass `SparkConf` parameter explicitly from ADF pipeline like below
to reflect in Spark job?

```
 "sparkConfig": {
     "spark.app.name": "SparkAppForStudent"
 }
```

Thanks